# How can i create a position-time graph of a object which is moving in 3D space? Is it even possible?

Tags: kinematics, spacetime-dimensions, visualization

As modelling position-time graph of a object 2D in motion requires 3 dimensions, is it possible to create a 3D object's position-time graph? Is there any intuitive idea through which it can be represented in 3d space?

Comment: Yes, But you'd need 4 dimensions, a little thing our 3d minds can't digest.

Comment: Do you want the graph to have 2 dimensions, or 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use 3 dimensions for position and for time, you can use colours.

Say, you tracked the motion of a body in 3d space. Plot it on a 3d graph and as time increases, the wavelength of your line (or curve) increases (the colour changes as time increases).

For me, this idea seemed pretty interesting because i don't usually come up with ideas.

Answer (score 1):

### Computer Simulation

3D simulations that evolve with time can be one solution to this problem. We can make 3-dimensional models on the computer and we can seek through them just like we seek through 2d videos. We can move forward and backward and watch the simulation evolve. Once a point in time is selected, we may explore the particular model on the computer by changing our point of view to study the simulation in 3d at that point in time. Since we are not capable of even imagining 4 dimensions, this should be our best bet on making 4d "graphs".